# Stateful Widget in a ListView is not getting updated

Tags: flutter, stateful, statefulwidget

I have a list of all deals `_deals` and a list of selected deals `_selectedDeals`. Deals can be added to or removed from the list `_selectedDeals` from another class. So if a new deal is added/removed, I want to rebuild this `DealsWidget` so the newly added/removed deal is properly reflected in UI.

And I'm using `BookButton` stateful widget, to show if a deal is selected or not. When `isBooked` is true, it means that the deal is selected.

I planned to achieve this behavior by calling the `refresh()` function of `DealsWidget` after data is added/removed from that other class so it would rebuild everything and my UI is consistent with data, but nothing happened.

What I've found out is that rebuilding won't recreate `BookButton` widgets again. Their constructors are not called again. And that is why my updated value is not getting entertained, because I'm passing them in constructor of `BookButton`.

Can anyone explain why is this happening and how can I properly show which deals are selected and which are not?

**DealsWidget**

```
class DealsWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Deal> _deals;
  final List<Deal> _selectedDeals;

  final DealSelectionListener _dealSelectionListener;

  DealsWidget(
    Key dealsKey,
    this._deals,
    this._selectedDeals,
    this._dealSelectionListener,
  ) : super(key: dealsKey);

  @override
  DealsWidgetState createState() => DealsWidgetState();
}

class DealsWidgetState extends State<DealsWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final totalDeals = widget._deals.length;

    return ListView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: totalDeals,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

        final deal = widget._deals[index];
        final isSelected = widget._selectedDeals.contains(deal);
        
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
          child: BookButton(
            isSelected,
            (isBooked) {
              if (isBooked) {
                widget._dealSelectionListener._onSelected(deal);
              } else {
                widget._dealSelectionListener._onDeselected(deal);
              }
            }
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }

  void refresh() {

    print('Refreshing deals');

    setState(() {
      
    });
  }
}
```

**BookButton**

```
class BookButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final bool isBooked;
  final OnBookChangedListener listener;

  BookButton(this.isBooked, this.listener);

  @override
  BookButtonClass createState() => BookButtonClass(isBooked);
}
  
class BookButtonClass extends State<BookButton> {

  bool isBooked;

  BookButtonClass(this.isBooked);

  void check(bool check) {
    setState(() {
      isBooked = check;
      widget.listener.call(isBooked);
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          isBooked = !isBooked;
          widget.listener.call(isBooked);
        });
      },
      child: Text(
        isBooked ? AppStrings.unbook.toUpperCase() : AppStrings.book.toUpperCase(),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: isBooked ? AppColors.accentColor : Colors.white,
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        side: BorderSide(
          color: AppColors.accentColor,
          width: isBooked ? 1 : 0,
        )
      ),
      color: isBooked ? Colors.transparent : AppColors.accentColor,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to look at this https://dartpad.dev/3d7ca93535204901fe67776d9678b0b7. I know this is far from your question but it might give you an idea on just using setstate().. this example, uses a static global class to hold, read, update data and with setstate it will notify some changes.

Comment: @Reign I've check it, it is doing the same thing I'm doing. But it's not working at my end. Maybe because my widgets are in a `List`?

Answer (score 0):

in this case you should use a Provider, becouse the widget needs to known when to rebuild.

Or if you think that Provider its kind of hard to learn now, try using a SetState() on your event ClickButton, this shoud resolve

Look what i did in my Case

So in my class with the data i used a the change changeNotifier

```
class PartnerControler extends ChangeNotifier {
....
changeNotifiers()
}
```

in the display class i used this

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => partnerControler,
                  child: buildPartnerList(context),
                ),

 Widget buildPartnerList(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
Consumer<PartnerControler>(
          builder: (context, partnercontroler, child) {
return (Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
itemCount: partnerControler.partnerListFiltered.length,
..
```

Comment: I don't know about `Provider`. But I _am_ calling `setState()` on my event. The event happens in another class. It adds/removes data and then I call `refresh()` function, which calls `setState()`

Comment: See if my example can help you